# Why doesn't using keys from two sides of a union cause TS to complain?

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't this cause a TS error?  [TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20T%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7C%20%7B%20b%3A%20string%20%7D%0A%0Aconst%20obj%3A%20T%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20'a'%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20'd'%2C%0A%7D)

```
type T = { a: string } | { b: string }

const obj: T = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'd',
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get mutual exclusivity and excess property check one workaround is to do this

```
export type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;
export type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };


type T = XOR<{ a: string }, { b: string }>

const obj: T = {
  a: 'a',
} // passes

const obj1: T = {
  b: 'b',
} // passes

const obj2: T = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
} // fails
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the only thing that would cause TS to complain is [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks), and it's not done for non-discriminated union types. [There's open issue for that](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863), reported Dec 22, 2017.

See also [Union type does not act as mutual exclusion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31055), where the answer is "it never was intended to".